# Adding string-number pairs to an array (from array), so that recurring strings increment the number instead of being added again

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, associative-array

How to insert items from an array (of item-number pairs) in a way so that if the item has already been added, we increment the number associated with the item?

So when we first add the item, we set the number associated with it to 1.

The reason I am doing this is to have a list of items with a number of how many times they occurred in the input array.

If there is a better way of receiving that result, I will gladly accept those answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can accomplish this using a dictionary (known as `map` in some other languages).

```
li = ['Item#1', 'Item#2', 'Item#3', 'Item#1', 'Item#4', 'Item#1']

dict_map = {}  # we can also use defaultdict

for item in li:
    dict_map[item] = dict_map.get(item, 0) + 1

print(dict_map)
```

Output:

```
{'Item#1': 3, 'Item#2': 1, 'Item#3': 1, 'Item#4': 1}
```

You can use the JavaScript equivalent of this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = ['apple', 'cherry', 'orange'];

let res = {};

array.forEach(x => res[x] = 0);

function add(item) {
  res[item]++;
  document.getElementById(item).innerHTML = res[item]++;

  console.log(res);
}
```

```html
<div>Apple <span id="apple">0</span></div>
<div>Cherry <span id="cherry">0</span></div>
<div>Orange <span id="orange">0</span></div>

<button onclick="add('apple')">addApple</button>
<button onclick="add('cherry')">addCherry</button>
<button onclick="add('orange')">addOrange</button>
```

Comment: Or, if you need array of items: https://jsfiddle.net/kompanietst/gm8yd6j4/